# Firefox: input field number min max not working

Tags: html, firefox

I'm facing the issue for input field's attributes **min** and **max** values in Firefox (v_30.0) browser.

This works

```
<input name="year" type="number" placeholder="YYYY" required min="1" max="12"/>
```

But this does not

```
<input name="year" type="number" placeholder="YYYY" required min="1990" max="20014"/>
```

it displays `1` on input box and does not move further.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firefox (unlike Chrome) seems to follow the HTML5 definition for [stepping up](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#dom-input-stepup) the value of an `input type=number` element. When the value is not set, as it here isn’t initially, it is interpreted as 0, so the result of incrementing is 1. Since it is outside the range, it is an invalid value, and further stepping is not possible.

This means that `input type=number` is intended for use with quantities for which an initial value can be set (or the default initial value of 0 can be accepted). After all, stepping up and down is really the reason for using this element type, and it needs to start somewhere.

Consequently, there is not much point in using `required` for such an element, unless the implicit default of 0 is acceptable and within the bounds set.

If you still want to use `input type=number`, you need to set some initial value with the `value` attribute that is within the bounds. Technically, this means that the `pattern` attribute has no effect.

To read a required 4-digit number when no default value is set, optionally with a placeholder, you can use a text input field with suitable attributes (but you cannot express a range requirement in HTML, in any reasonable way, in this approach):

```html
<input name="year" type="text" placeholder="YYYY"
  size="4" maxlength="4" pattern="\d[4}" required
  style="font-family: Consolas, monospace">
```

Answer (score 1):

Just set the starting value and it will work

```
<input name="year" type="number"  min="1990" max="2014" value="1990" required />
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ywq6dq93/

**EDIT:**

As another user previously pointed out, this will not show the placeholder but instead the starting value of 1990. In Chrome it works to not set the value and still show the placeholder and achieve the desired functionality, however it seems that in FF you would need to set the value by javascript when focusing on the input field, if you want to show a placeholder instead of a starting value.

Demo for this: http://jsfiddle.net/1pg5727f

Comment: your code seems to be work fine... but when i scroll the focus event is not being trigger in my case.

Comment: What do you mean by "When I scroll"? It's supposed to set the starting value to 1990 when you focus the input field, I.E clicknig it for example.

Comment: This approach also has the problem that the `required` attribute becomes useless, since the control always has a value (the initial value set).

Comment: "when i scroll" means to move up/down arrows of input box

Answer (score 0):

```html
<input type="number" step="1" min="1"  name="product_qty" value="1" title="Qty" class="input-text" size="4" maxlength="10" pattern="\d*" required />
```

Answer (score -2):

if you still looking for the answer you can use input type="number".
min max work if it set in that order:
1-name
2-maxlength
3-size
4-min
5-max
just copy it

```
<input  name="X" maxlength="3" size="2" min="1" max="100" type="number" />
```